# By using Alphabetic character/index in listview searching name in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I would like to implement a ListView with fastscroll and albhabet indexer as in the contacts application. I'm using a SimpleAdapter to populate the ListView. As seen from the image, by selecting a letter from the alphabet indexer at the right, the listView  selection goes to the corresponding ListItem. How to accomplish this? Please share some examples. Thank u In advance.

[image]